# how do pronounce assignment = in math or programming?

Tags: usage, mathematics, reading-aloud

I know you read equality `==` in `if (x == 5)` this way:

> If x is equal to 5 . . .

But how do you read it in a coding context (assignment); i.e. `=` in `x` = `5`?

Comment: I would say "5 is assigned to x", or "x is filled with 5"... but I'm not native english. In my native language (french), there is no way to say it "nicely". We would better talk of "x is initialized to 5".

Comment: I would say *for X equal to 5*

Comment: The first question (which nobody asked) should be: What programming language is this, that uses double "=" signs?  Because yours is not a question about English; it is about that programming language.  In BASIC , assigment is "LET A=B" (let A equal B) In C, you can say things such as "B++" (increment B). How you say it has nothing to do with English rules; it depends on the programming language's syntax.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question of "English" but strictly field specific.  The point of code is to avoid the ambiguity of natural language.  So asking how to render computer code in natural language is quixotic

Comment: @JamesK I think if we limited the question to math, it's OK as a "how do I read this aloud" question, but I agree that how to read code aloud is out of scope (especially since `x = 5` could mean different things in different programming languages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are very minor differences but they are basically the same:

### Comparison

```
if (x == 5)
```

Is pronounced - *if x is equal to five*

### Assignment

```
x = 5
```

Is pronounced - *x equals five*

Another, more technical way (the above is a colloquial term) is *set x to five*.

Comment: "x = 5" in programming is not an equality... it puts the value "5" in the variable "x"... so I don't think we would say "x equals five".

Comment: @Random Yes I know, but you still say it in the same way

Comment: So you are pretty sure about `x equals five`, aren't u?

Comment: @Milad I often use it in conversation about mathematical equations or programs

Comment: @Milad: Beta's answer here is sound. [*In some languages (notably Fortran), the equality symbol and the assignment symbol are the same, and many people say: **"x equals e"** when they mean **"store the value of e in x,"** or **"x becomes e.***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+equality+symbol+and+the+assignment+symbol+are+the+same%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: This is also what I've always said and heard. I would resort to "set x to 5" when there's a chance of ambiguity. (You might think there always is, but one is a statement and the other an expression, so they rarely appear in the same contexts in most programming languages.)

Answer (score 0):

**Programming Answer:**

> If (x == 5) { (code) }

tells the computer:

> If (x is equal to 5) { Do this code }

While

> x = 5

tells the computer

> The variable x currently has the value of 5. (Anywhere the variable "x" is used the value of 5 will replace it unless x is changed later)

The reason we use "==" for "equals" is because we had already decided that " = " means "is assigned to"

---

**Math Answer**

In algebra and calculus "x = 5" would be "x equals 5"

Comment: So how do pronounce eventually? the same algebra way?

Comment: I always say x=5 as "x equals five" @Milad even though it is *technically* incorrect.